# Can "avert to" be used to mean allude?

Tags: word-usage

> In particular, many of the early...were in part inspired by learnability considerations.[...]And later research has often **averted to** learnability considerations as well [references omitted].
> (from Jackendoff, 2002)

Because the cited papers are all about learnability, it seems "averted to" is used as *mention* or *allude* here. Is this acceptable?

Find [here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/Avert/xllmj/post.htm) another question on similar lines. My example is from careful and edited American prose, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a mistake for [*advert*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/advert#Etymology_2) (which is pretty rare as a verb now anyway). Neither the OED nor Wiktionary records "avert" in this sense.

Comment: Probly compounded by confusing  _allude_ and _elude_ (which actually does have some semantics in common with _avert_).

Comment: Yes, advert it is: "To call attention; refer. Used with to: He adverted to the problem in the opening paragraph." [From The American Heritage Dictionary].